# ajax call make my json object become [object Object] in http request parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, parameters, request

My development environment:

```
Spring MVC 4.1.2
jackson 2.4.4
```

I am trying send a complex JSON object to my spring MVC control by jQuery 1.7.2's ajax call:

```
function uploadFileAjaxCall(fileid,filedata,filename,filetype,referid,remark){
var jsonData = {fileId:fileid,fileData: filedata, fileName: filename,fileType:filetype,referId:referid,fileRemark:remark}
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "uploadFileByPartner",
    processData:false,
    type: 'GET',
    data: jsonData,/*{json: JSON.stringify(jsonData)},*/
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");//"application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");// "application/json");
    },success:function(response){
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=response;
        },error:function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
};
```

There are six values in the JSON object, filedata field is byte array, it is about couple of hundreds to a mega bytes. anything else is very small size. This function was used to send a file to server without using form submit.

my POJO class as:

```
public class FileEntity implements serialisable{
   private String fileId;
   private byte[] fileData;
   private String fileName;
   private String fileType;
   private String referId;
   private String fileRemark;

   set/get.........

}
```

my controller looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/uploadFileByPartner", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String uploadFileByPartner(WebRequest webrequest, HttpServletRequest request){
    Map<String, String[]> parameters = webrequest.getParameterMap();
    System.out.println("passed in parameters : "+parameters.toString());
    return null;
}
```

When I tried to send it over http, I can't use POST, I have to use GET. When I use POST, my tomcat fire http status 400.

when I check my http connectivity in my firefox firebug, the request parameters as:

```
[object Object]
```

there is no other details information.

The catalina print out as:

```
passed in parameters : {[object Object]=[Ljava.lang.String;@110732aa}
```

seems it is a binary string or byte array.

I can't retrieve the object from the HttpServletRequest.

I tried to use:

```
@RequestBody FileEntity file
```

in the request parameter to accept JSON object injection, but I never get it work.

I was blocked here.

all advise and comment are welcome.

Comment: Have you tried with `Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();` (It's `request` and not `webRequest`)

Comment: You can also try with `@RequestParam Map<String,String> allParams` as the method argument.

Comment: I tried retrieve it through Map<String, String>, but unfortunately, it is only one key with out any value, that means it is not a Map, it is only a [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by my self.

1. prepare JSON map format have to be formalised as {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
2. configure servlet property file to enable JSON object mapper to support json/POJO map.
3. Have to make JSON map pair match with POJO entity fields. set

   @RequestBody FileEntity file

as parameter to be inject into.

all works fine from now.